# If a photon is in a early/late superposition how can those states be either in-phase or out-phase?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, superposition, quantum-teleportation

[image]

I'm trying to understand this [image](http://www.sciencealert.com/images/oct-15/nist_quantum_teleportation_infographic_fullsize.gif). Full article is [here](http://www.sciencealert.com/a-new-quantum-teleportation-distance-record-has-been-set).

I do understand why the photon after step 1 is in superposition if early and late state. However I don't understand why those states are either in phase or out of phase.

Why aren't they always in-phase?
Why are they either exactly in phase or out of phase and never somewhere in between (why can't the waves be just a little off)?

Comment: Distance translates to phase, so with the right amount of delay one can design it so that it is exactly out of phase.

Comment: @flippiefanus Yes, if I know what wavelength photons I'm using I can make one path just as much longer so that outcoming photon has out-of-phase superposition. However if I understand the poster right, then the photon (after step 1 before going into crystal) can be either in or out of phase. Why is it not the same for all photons if the setup and wavelength of photons is not changed?

Comment: Unfortunately the article in the link does not really give enough information to understand exactly what they did. One needs to second guess what they mean by all the simplified language. One would need to read the original article. Are you interested in the general way that teleportation works?

Comment: @flippiefanus I understand how it works mathematically (for example I have no problems understanding Formal presentation chapter in Quantum teleportation Wikipedia article), but I don't know how it really works. I know and maybe understand a few ways how some particles are used as qubits, but this is where my knowledge ends. Now I'm trying to understand what scientists actually do when they perform these teleportations (what they do to entangle particles, transport them etc).

Comment: It is mostly a mathematics thing. When you have a tensor product of some state $\psi$ with an entangled state and you rearrange the expression so that the pair of photons that will take part in the joint measurements are collected in terms of all possible entangled states then the state of the remaining photon (one from the original entangled pair) will be the same, up to a possible unitary transformation, as the state $\psi$. I can expand on this in an answer, but then your question would need to require such an answer.